# If user has 1 post then dont let him create new one

Tags: posts, limit

I have tryied all plugins.
I need a php code not a plugin cause im running a front end post creator.
I need a function or a php code which only allows a user to have 1 post only but if that post is deleted he can then make a new post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are explicitly asking for a coded solution without demonstrating research or implementation efforts on your own part. Please review the "[ask]" page in our [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [count_user_posts function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/count_user_posts/).
If the posts are getting saved as WordPress posts then it can be done by the snippet below:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()){
    $userPostCount = count_user_posts(get_current_user_id());
    if ($userPostCount > 1){
        $user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());
        $user->add_cap('publish_posts',false);
    } else {
        $user->add_cap('publish_posts',true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for dashboard but didnt work with front end poster ''DJD Site Post''

Comment: Is there a way to hide this without javascript for example? `<button type="submit" class="send-button" id="submit"><?php echo ( $djd_options['djd-send-button'] ? $djd_options['djd-send-button'] : __('Publish', 'djd-site-post') ); ?></button>`

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with "DJD Site Post" plugin. you can use CSS or add inline style, or you can add a condition in php to not echo if condition is not met.